# map with panel plots

Tags: r, plot, gis, lattice

I am following the excellent example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/89226). Everything works until the grid plotting,

```
library("lattice")
spplot(sp_grd, "id", colorkey=FALSE,
       panel = function(...) {
         panel.gridplot(..., border="black", col.regions="white")
         sp.polygons(shp)
         sp.points(poi, cex=1.5)
         panel.text(..., col="red")
       })
```

When I attempt this plotting, I get the error,

'Error using packet 1
formal argument "col.regions" matched by multiple actual arguments'.

Any ideas for fixes? Basically I don't want the panels to be filled in with colours, as it defaults to do.

EDIT: Reproducible example modified from link.

```
### read shapefile
library("rgdal")
library("lattice")
library("rworldmap")
shp <- getMap(resolution="low")

### define coordinates and convert to SpatialPointsDataFrame
poi <- data.frame(x=c(15, 25, 35, 100),
                  y=c(-15, 25, -35, -50),
                  id="A", stringsAsFactors=F)
coordinates(poi) <- ~ x + y
proj4string(poi) <- proj4string(shp)

### define SpatialGrid object
bb <- bbox(shp)
cs <- c(10, 10)
cc <- bb[, 1] + (cs/2)  # cell offset
cd <- ceiling(diff(t(bb))/cs)  # number of cells per direction
grd <- GridTopology(cellcentre.offset=cc, cellsize=cs, cells.dim=cd)

sp_grd <- SpatialGridDataFrame(grd,
                               data=data.frame(id=1:prod(cd)),
                               proj4string=CRS(proj4string(shp)))
# does work
spplot(sp_grd, "id",
       panel = function(...) {
         panel.gridplot(..., border="black")
         sp.polygons(shp)
         sp.points(poi, cex=1.5)
         panel.text(...)
       })

# does not work
spplot(sp_grd, "id",
       panel = function(...) {
         panel.gridplot(..., border="black", col.regions="white")
         sp.polygons(shp)
         sp.points(poi, cex=1.5)
         panel.text(...)
       })
```

Comment: Supply a minimal reproducible example, and I'll give you an answer.

Comment: Right-o, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting that error message because `panel.gridplot()` is being passed two different arguments named `col.regions`. You've supplied one explicitly, and the other is being (by default) passed on through the dots (`...`) argument of your panel function.

The solution is to add `col.regions` as a formal argument to your panel function. That way, it'll capture the `col.regions` argument coming from outside (i.e. from `spplot()`), removing it from the list of otherwise unmatched arguments that get soaked up by `...`. Your call to `panel.gridplot()` will then only have one argument named `col.regions=`, and will work as you expected it to.

This will do the trick:

```
spplot(sp_grd, "id", colorkey=FALSE,
       panel = function(..., col.regions) {
         panel.gridplot(..., border="black", col.regions="white")
         sp.polygons(shp)
         sp.points(poi, cex=1.5)
         panel.text(...)
})
```

Comment: I knew it would be something like this, but I somehow wasn't seeing it. Thanks!

Comment: @noname Certainly! Always happy to help folks who are using **lattice** graphics.